# How to pass a variable inside quotes on Python?

Tags: python, docker, variables

I'm using the docker-py SDK and I need to pass some variables inside the `containers.run`.

What I need:

```
MYDIR = '/variable/dir'
MYURL = 'https://example.com'
client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.run(image="alpine:latest", name="container", user="1000", volumes=['MYDIR:/tmp'], command=["/bin/sh", "echo MYURL"])
```

What I get:
One error after other.

As you can see I need to put the variables inside the quotes of *volumes* and *command*.

I tried various combinations without any luck: with quotes, without them, using str concatenation, etc...

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember this -- the strings do not actually contain any quotes.  Quotes are just the method we have to use to write literal strings in Python code.  If you're putting strings in a configuration file to be read by Python, then you do not need quotes.

Comment: Can you show your errors, please?

Comment: Sure @wkl.
example: 
```
MYDIR = "/variable/dir"
client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.run(image="alpine:latest", name="container", user="1000", volumes=['MYDIR:/tmp'], command=["/bin/sh", "echo MYURL"])
```
I get the following error:
```
docker.errors.APIError: 400 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/containers/create?name=container: Bad Request ("create MYDIR/resources: "MYDIR/resources" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path")
``

Comment: But @TimRoberts what happens in this case when the docker SDK asks for quotes in their commands?

Comment: `MYDIR` is a Python variable.  Docker knows nothing about that.  You want `volumes=[MYDIR+'/tmp']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to combine a string from a variable with another string. There are many ways to do this in Python. The latest way is called f-strings, which are very close to your "pass a variable inside quotes" in terms of syntax (although that's an oversimplification of what's actually happening).

For example:

```
container = client.containers.run(image="alpine:latest", 
                name="container", user="1000", volumes=[f'{MYDIR}/tmp'],
                command=["/bin/sh", f"echo {MYURL}"])
```

Note that each string into which we have inserted a variable 1) begins with an `f` before the opening quote marks (hence "f-strings"—the `f` is for formatted) and 2) places the variable in `{...}` brackets. You can actually use any expression inside the brackets, not just a single variable name.